# Why doesn't `global` statement affect blocks inside current block?

Tags: python, scoping

```
def foo():
    global a
    def bar():
        nonlocal a
        a = 6
    bar()

a = 5
foo()
print(a)
```

Trying to run a module consisting of code listed above results in `SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'a' found`. But I expected that it would run and print `6`, why doesn't it?

Notice, that if we replace the `global a` statement with a statement that binds the name `a` (e.g. `from something import otherthing as a` or `a = 0`), then there's no `SyntaxError`, and the `print(a)` statement outputs `5` as expected.

I read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding but didn't understand what `global` and `nonlocal` statements do.

Comment: [Python nonlocal statement](//stackoverflow.com/q/1261875)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is bound in the top level namespace.

> The `nonlocal` statement causes corresponding names to refer to previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing function scope.

But `a` is not bound in a function scope so

> `SyntaxError` is raised at compile time

In other words `global` does not affect where `a` is bound.

Comment: So, constructs that bind names (e.g. assignment) do 2 things: bind that name in the current block, and make all uses of the name in the current block refer to this binding. While `global` only makes all uses of the name in the current block refer to the binding in the global scope. Right?

Comment: @CrabMan Give or take some pedantic quibbling about phrasing, I'd agree with that

Answer (score -2):

```
a = 5
def foo():
    global a
    def bar():
        global a
        a = 6
    bar()
foo()
print(a)
```

this prints 6

The nonlocal statement causes corresponding names to refer to previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing function scope.